# unable to compile a code with list of Future

Tags: scala

There are some suggestions on StackOverflow on how to handle a list of Futures but I want to try my own approach. But I am unable to compile the following code

I have a list of Futures. 
I want to count how many of them passed or failed. I should get (2,1) 
I store this in a tuple
The approach I want to take is go through each element of the list. The element of the list is Future[Int]. for each element, I call flatMap which calls the next cycle of recursion (I am assuming that if flatMap gets called then that particular future would have been successful so I increment pass count). Similarly, I want to call next cycle of recursion in recover and increment fail count but I am getting compilation error in it.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object ConcurrencyExample extends App {

  type pass = Int
  type fail = Int

  val time = System.currentTimeMillis()

//use recursion to process each Future in the list 
  def segregate(l:List[Future[Int]]):Future[Tuple2[pass,fail]] = {
    def go(l:List[Future[Int]],t:Tuple2[pass,fail]):Future[Tuple2[pass,fail]] = {
        l match {
          case Nil => Future{t}
            //l is List of Future[Int]. flatMap each successful Future 
            //recover each failed Future
          case l::ls => {
            l flatMap (x => go(ls, (t._1 + 1, t._2)))
              **l.recover({ case e => go(ls, (t._1 + 1, t._2))})**//I get error here
          }
        }
    }
    go(l,(0,0))
  }

//hardcoded future
  val futures2: List[Future[Int]] = List(Future {
    1
  }, Future {
    2
  }, Future {
    throw new Exception("error")
  })


  val result = segregate(futures2)
  result onComplete {
    case Success(v) => println("pp:" + v)
    case Failure(v) => println("fp:" + v)
  }

  Await.result(result,1000 millis)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@evan058 is correct about the signature of recover. But you can fix your program by changing *recover* to *recoverWith*.

*recoverWith* is to *recover* as *flatMap* is to *map*.

Here's the complete solution (with minor stylistic improvements):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object ConcurrencyExample extends App {

  type pass = Int
  type fail = Int

  val time = System.currentTimeMillis()

  //use recursion to process each Future in the list
  def segregate[T](fs:List[Future[T]]):Future[(pass,fail)] = {
    def go(fs:List[Future[T]],r:Future[(pass,fail)]):Future[(pass,fail)] = fs match {
      case Nil => r
      case l::ls =>
        val fx = l.transform({_ => (1, 0)}, identity).recoverWith[(pass,fail)]({case _: Exception => Future(0, 1) })
        for (x <- fx; t <- r; g <- go(ls, Future(t._1+x._1,t._2+x._2))) yield g
    }
    go(fs,Future((0,0)))
  }

  //hardcoded future
  val futures2 = List(Future(1), Future(2), Future(throw new Exception("error")))    

  val result = segregate(futures2)
  result onComplete {
    case Success(v) => println(s"successes: ${v._1}, failures: ${v._2}")
    case Failure(v) => v.printStackTrace()
  }

  Await.result(result,1000 millis)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't OP still have a `(pass,fail)` rather than some `U` where `U >: Int`?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you meant. Looks like you would need a `asInstanceOf[Future[(pass,fail)]]` otherwise it complains about getting a `Future[Any]`, but after that it runs for me.

Comment: Gents - Thanks. Do you mean this ?The code compiles but I get a runtime error  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2` The code I have written now is  `flatMap (x => go(ls, (t._1 + 1, t._2)))
          l.asInstanceOf[Future[(pass,fail)]].recoverWith({ case e => go(ls, (t._1 + 1, t._2))})`

Comment: I rewrote it -- but I can't format the code here in the comment nicely so am adding a new answer

Comment: It's looking much better now although it would be nice to make it tail-recursive. Maybe I'll come back to work on that later. Or somebody else will...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U>:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]), the signature of `recover` is:

```
def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U]
```

You are calling `recover` on `l` which is a `Future[Int]` so `recover` is expecting a `U >: Int`.

However you are calling `go` again which has the return type `Future[(pass, fail)]` which is not `>: Int`.